# Seeing double-cursor in 'recursive RDP'

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, microsoft-virtual-pc

I'm using a Virtual PC VM on my PC to connect to a remote PC using RDP over a VPN. It works just fine except that in the RDP session, I often see a double mouse cursor... I get a standard mouse-arrow *and* the context-specific cursor such as a caret or hourglass.

It's not a big problem but rather annoying and I wondered if there's any way to fix it, or at least understand where it comes from? Is it because I'm effectively running one RDP session from inside another?

My host PC runs W7, my local VM runs XP, and the remote PC access using RDP is W7.

Thankyou for any help.

Comment: The might be something at this [Remote Desktop Hacks](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/04/19/remote-desktop-hacks.aspx) website that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the issue by turning off cursor shadowing on the remote machine, after finding this article: http://citrixblogger.org/2008/02/07/cursor-shadowing-turn-it-off/

Comment: Dead link unfortunately